# TypeScript: namespaces throwing "property does not exist"

Tags: typescript

I have TypeScript code that was working fine in a project, but in my brand new project it does no longer work.

I am using `namespaces` to structure my app:

app.ts:

```
namespace App {
    export function render() {...}
    export function onRouteNotFound() {...}
}
```

main.ts:

```
App.onRouteNotFound();
```

This is throwing:

`main.ts(33,8): error TS2339: Property 'onRouteNotFound' does not exist on type 'typeof App'.`

More complex now:

controller/category.ts:

```
namespace App.Controller.Category {
    export function details() {
        App.render(...);
    }
}
```

Still throwing:

`controller/category.ts(5,7): error TS2339: Property 'render' does not exist on type 'typeof App'.`

It was working fine with classes and functions, but I don't want to use that. I prefer the "staticness" of namespaces.

How am I supposed to make this work?

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "public/**/*.ts",
        "app/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any input! (this code really is almost the same as with another app, but I did not use the same build chain and maybe did not have the most recent typescript version, I dunno)

Using tsc v2.7.2

Comment: How are you referencing the other files, i.e. how do you load `main.js` and `app.js`?

Comment: Via tsconfig.include. But I gave up and switched to vanilla js. I have to be efficient and productive, otherwise I risk dropping this project and I wouldn't want that. Plus I saw that namespaces were "the old way" apparently... Thanks anyway for your help Fenton! It's greatly appreciated

Comment: I had this issue and solved it by making sure my `tsconfig.json` was properly including the files that the error was referencing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but in case others are still running into the same problem, I think I figured something out.

If you add `/// <reference path="app.ts" />` comments to the other files (main.ts, and controller/category.ts), TypeScript will compile.

Then you can actually remove those comments and TypeScript still compiles. Seems like buggy behaviour, but possibly why it was working in one project, but failed when copied to a new one.

Splitting a namespace across multiple files is described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files) in the TypeScript documentation.